# How do I rigorously show a sequence of positive real numbers converges to a non-negative real number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> If $x_n >0$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and $x_n\to x$ as $n \to \infty$, prove that $x \ge 0$.

Suppose $x<0$. Since $x_n \to x$, then for all $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies |x_n-x|< \epsilon$.

I know we must have infinitely many terms of the sequence close to $x$, but does this say there must exist infinitely many negative terms in the sequence? If so, how?

Comment: Think about the case $x=-1$; why cannot a sequence of positive numbers converge to $-1$?

Comment: Because we must have terms in the sequence arbitrarily close to $1$. But how about if we choose an extremely small negative number, say $-\epsilon$?

Comment: No matter how small it is it still has a significant absolute value.  Let $|x| > \epsilon > 0$.  Then $|x_n - x| > \epsilon$ for all $n$.  Which contradicts convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $x<0$, then there exists some $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|x_{n}-x|<-x/2$, then $x_{n}=x_{n}-x+x\leq|x_{n}-x|+x<-x/2+x=x/2<0$.

Comment: Why must there exist an $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies |x_n-x| < -x/2$? Why $-x/2$?

Comment: Put the so called $\epsilon$ to be $-x/2$, note that $-x/2>0$, so it can be a candidate for such an $\epsilon$.

Comment: Got it. I see now.

Comment: Last question: How'd you come up with this so fast?

Comment: Draw the graph, actually you can take $\epsilon=-x$, the philosophy is, draw a small circle centred at $-x$ that not containing the zero, so the radius is no more than $-x$, then for eventually $x_{n}$ must lie in the small circle, then this is a contradiction, because all such $x_{n}$ are strictly positive.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. That helped me see the picture on the real number line. When you saw draw the graph, do you mind the real number line, or the plane, something else?

Comment: Of course strictly speaking you should imagine on the line, then the so called circle is an open interval, but in principle the philosophy has no much difference.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is negative and $x_n$ is given to be positive (or more generally non-negative) then $|x_n-x|\geq |x|$ and there is no way to make the difference $|x_n-x|$ smaller than $|x|$ and this contradicts the fact that $x_n\to x$. Therefore we must have $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The precise form of "...infinitely many terms close to $x\;$" is that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$ iff for every $e>0$ the set $S(e)=\{n: x_n\not \in (-e+x,e+x)\}$ is finite.

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x<0$ then with $e=|x|/2,$ the set $S(|x|/2)=\{n: x_n\not \in (-3|x|/2,-|x|/2)\}$ is finite, which implies that $\{n: x_n> 0\}$ is a subset of the $finite$ set $S(|x|/2),$ so it cannot be true that $x_n>0$ for all $n.$

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of looking at this using Topology.

Since $\mathbb R$ is a metrizable space, then it is first-countable and thus it is sequential.

The set $S = [0, + \infty) \subset \mathbb R$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R$ and so any convergent sequence from $S$ will have its limit lying inside $S$.

Now since your convergent sequence by assumption lies inside $\{ x \in \mathbb R \ | \ x \gt 0\} \subset S$ then its limit must be contained in $S$ by the above logic.

This implies that the limit is non-negative.

Answer (score -1):

Because every negative number has a neighborhood consisting of negative numbers only.